# how to create jabberd xmpp client in ios9 using swift2

Tags: swift2, ios9, ejabberd, xmppframework, xcode7.2

[image]I am following this link 
https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios

but am getting couple of errors which are as follows

1.Could not build ObjectiveC module 'XMPPFramework'

2.CocoaAsyncSocket/GCDAsyncSocket.h file not found.

I have tried out ways such as

Built Setting on your project, then setting it like

User Header Search Paths = $(SRCROOT)   // recursive. 
Always Search User Paths = YES

But still errors persist.
Please help

Comment: Did you install xmpp-messenger-ios using CocoaPods?

Comment: yes i did install the pod files and installation was completed properly.But still the above situation arises

Comment: I have added the pod installation image for you to have a look.

Comment: @AnandYadav did you find the solution buddy :)

Comment: @Mr.bean yes i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the project, you need to have Cocoapods installed.

Then, you can check out the latest version of the project with Xcode 7.2.1 and open Example/xmpp-messenger-ios.xcworkspace

On first build all dependencies should be properly downloaded, but you need to use workspace and not project with Cocoapods.

Comment: Yes i have cocoa pods installed. All dependencies  are  downloaded properly and installed. And i am using workspace. But can you please suggest the Fixes/Steps to avoid above errors.

Comment: 1.Could not build ObjectiveC module 'XMPPFramework'

2.CocoaAsyncSocket/GCDAsyncSocket.h file not found.

Comment: Then if you load workspace it should build fine. I tried from scratch and all went fine.

Comment: can you suggest fixes for https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios/issues/43. As issues faced by me are similar.